# Once I submit patent forms can I start selling my invention and it be protected?

Tags: patent-applications, design-patent

Basically I want to know if once I submit the micro patent form, is my invention protected if I start selling it to companies?

Comment: Filing an application does not insure you will be granted a patent.

Comment: And filing it yourself does so even less.

Answer (score 2):

The only "micro form" I know of with the USPTO is the form/checkbox to claim micro-entity status to get reduced fees. I assume you are talking about the filing of an application. Once you file an application, either provisional or non-provisional, you can disclose your invention and not break novelty. For the U.S. you have a quasi grace period of a year so you could have chosen to disclose a year before filing. It is not generally recommended and any disclosure before filing will keep you from ever getting any protection other than in the U.S.

It may be that your application is not detailed enough or has some other problem such that selling your product effectively discloses something you would like to have patented but is not covered in the application you filed. In that case you might need to file again and rely on the grace period - US only.

Any real protection only comes after a patent is issued. Up until then people could gamble that you will not get a patent and start copying your product.

Comment: Great answer. Your second paragraph is what most people overlook and decide to disclose their invention during the priority year, usually without any real need to do so. There have been many cases in which the disclosure ultimately precluded the applicant from getting patents granted. As you point out, grace period is only available in certain jurisdictions, so you are gambling if you decide to disclose the invention right after filing the first patent application.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go disclosing your invention, you better plan on having about $30, 000 to push the application through and if you don't have that + 3 years worth of living expense money someone can make sure you don't have a job.

Comment: "someone can make sure you don't have a job". I'm not sure what you mean by this. Perhaps you could clarify. Although you do make fine points about the cost and time necessary to obtain a patent, I think the answer could be improved upon.

Comment: if you file for a patent in a foreign country there is a 18-month sneak-peek which your invention gets published regardless if you ever get a patent granted on it or not this brings on heat in my case my own Australian patent lawyer filed for application figuring on someone would keep me in poverty so I could not get patents through it took me seven years to get a patent in the Great Britain and 11 years to get one in Canada. Ford Motor Company hired police to spread phony child molesters on me r

Comment: I am sorry to hear about the phony child molesters dennis sattler. At least they are phony right? And only YOU can keep you in poverty. L

Comment: @DennisSattler Ultimately we are trying to provide useful answers not only for this specific question, but for later viewers. This is best done by being as objective and impersonal as possible. I believe you have useful information to communicate and encourage you to edit and improve your answer.

Comment: I had serious doubts that the post would stay up for one reason or another. But I can assure you that what I say is true and and I even wrote a book about my first ten years of this experience. I bet you didn't know that Steven Spielberg's been in prison for over 5 years. Check out mystupidrules.com and Synchro link dot-com

Comment: Dear Frankleton,  after you go through 6 jobs in 2 weeks, jobs of which you did great for a couple days and your boss comes in looking for something to fire you for, there is something to it. I must say you have some Rose Colored Glasses don't you? Like you don't even know what goes on in your own country. It's called corruption.  A little foolish I must say but it's real and there is nothing you can do about it. It's called poverty forced upon you and you might find yourself in another country trying to get political Asylum just hoping you won't have to come back to it. You are naive as hell.